# Field level Deserialization not working with Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I am getting `400 Bad Request` error only when I am using field level deserialization with Jackson. If I am doing deserialization on a class level then it works fine. I only want to pass the user id instead of the whole user object, hence the field level deserialization. The deserializer is not even getting called as far as I can see. My code is as follows:

model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expense")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Expense implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "receiptPicture", column = @Column(name = "receipt_picture"))
})
private ExpenseDetail detail;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "given_by")
@JsonDeserialize(using = ExpenseGivenByDeserializer.class)
private User givenBy;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "given_for")
@JsonIgnore
private House givenFor;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_approved_expenses",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "expense_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}
)
@JsonIgnore
private List<User> approvedUsers;

@Embedded
@JsonIgnore
private Timer timer;

//....setters and getters
```

deserializer class:

```
    @Component
    public class ExpenseGivenByDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
        long id = node.get("givenBy").asLong();
        System.out.println("herer");
        return userDao.find(id);
    }
}
```

I am posting this:

```
{
    "detail" : {
        "description" : "rice 2 kg",
        "receiptPicture" : "../image/kk.jpg",
        "cost" : "1500"
    },
    "givenBy": 15
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your deserializer, `node` is the ***value node*** that you need. (check with `node.isValueNode()`).

This is enough

```
JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
long id = node.asLong();
System.out.println("herer"); //prints!

return userDao.find(id);
```